# Google Apps Script hangs while running a loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using this code but I can't see anything in the logger. I can just see a message "Preparing for execution"

```
function testfunc() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = s.getSheetByName("data")
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() - 1
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,2,lastRow,5).getValues()
  var fms = s.getSheetByName("FMS")
  for (var i = 0;i < data.length; ++i){
   var row = data[i]
   var a = row[0]
   var b = row[1]
   var c = row[2]
   var d = row[3]
   var e = row[4]
   Logger.log(i)
   if (i = 1) {
     Logger.log(i)
   }
  }
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

EDIT: As pointed out by @FedericoklezCulloca, I was missing an equal to sign in my if statement. The code should be :

```
function testfunc() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = s.getSheetByName("data")
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() - 1
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,2,lastRow,5).getValues()
  var fms = s.getSheetByName("FMS")
  for (var i = 0;i < data.length; ++i){
   var row = data[i]
   var a = row[0]
   var b = row[1]
   var c = row[2]
   var d = row[3]
   var e = row[4]
   Logger.log(i)
   if (i == 1) {
     Logger.log(i)
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (i = 1) {` did you mean `if (i == 1) {`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Oh, my dear lord! I was struggling with this for an hour now. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: So...is it solved? You're not logging any data. You should use `Logger.log(row)` or log one of the values (`var a, b...`, etc).

Comment: @BrianBennett Yes, it is solved. I was trying to debug the code using small variables here. I totally overlooked the missing equal to.